# getting tangent vectors for circle equation points

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, geometry, derivative

i'm trying to get the tangent vector for each point on the circle , i tried to use the derivative for the circle equation, but the result looks off in the viewport, so i'm wondering if i can find some help here

the code

```java
public void OnDrawGizmos(){
    step = (360.0f * Mathf.Deg2Rad) / numberOfPoints ;
    CreateVertices();
}


void CreateVertices()
{

    Points.Clear();
    Normals.Clear();
    Tangents.Clear();

    float dynamicAngle = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfPoints; i++)
    {
        Vector3 point;
        point.x = transform.position.x + Radius * Mathf.Cos(dynamicAngle);
        point.y = transform.position.y + Radius * Mathf.Sin(dynamicAngle);
        point.z = transform.position.z;


        dynamicAngle = dynamicAngle + step;
        if (i >= 1)
        {
            Gizmos.color = Color.red;
            Gizmos.DrawLine(Points[i - 1], point);
            Gizmos.color = Color.white;
        }
        Points.Add(point);
        CalculateNormals(dynamicAngle ,point);
        CalculateTangents(dynamicAngle,i  , point);

    }

}

void CalculateNormals(float dynamicAngle , Vector3 point)
{
    Vector3 Normal = (point - transform.position).normalized;

    Gizmos.color = Color.magenta;
    Gizmos.DrawLine(Normal, point);
    Gizmos.color = Color.white;

    Normals.Add(Normal);

}

void CalculateTangents(float dynamicAngle,int i  ,Vector3 point)
{
    Vector3 tangent;

      tangent = new Vector3(-Normals[i].y, Normals[i].x, 0);
      tangent.Normalize();

    Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
    Gizmos.DrawLine(  point, tangent);
    Gizmos.color = Color.white;

    Tangents.Add(tangent);
}
```

Blue is the tangents purple is the normals, as you can see they are not perpendicular:

[image: img]

To understand my issue better here is a gif from unity viewport:

[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already calculated the normals you can use the cross product to get the corresponding tangents

```cs
Vector3 up = new Vector3(0, 0, 1); // up side of your circle
Vector3 tangent = Vector3.Cross(normal, up);
```

If you only need to use circles on a specific plane you can also use this simplification

```cs
Vector3 tangent = new Vector3(-normal.y, normal.x, 0);
```

**Edit:**

The normals and tangents are direction vectors. They point from `point` in the direction the normal / tangent whould point. To draw the tangent, you have to pass the correct start and end points of the line by using

```cs
Gizmos.DrawLine(point, point + tangent);
```

If you move the GameObject away from the origin you will notice that the normals also get deformed, this has the same reason.

Comment: Hello Thanx for your answer ,this one works but not entirely , only when radius is close to 0
Vector3 Tangent = new Vector3(-Normal.y, Normal.x, 0);

still having issues when changing the radius 
do you have any idea why this occurs ,
please check the gif to understand my issue
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R2ZH.gif

Comment: this works like a charm ,don't know why i didn't see that before, thanx a lot

Comment: sorry can't rate you up , need more reputation i guess , hope someone do that for me

Comment: @BadrDouah don't worry about it, but you should be able to accept the answer (click on the check mark)

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2D parametric equations:

```
x = x0 + r*cos(a)
y = y0 + r*sin(a)
z = z0
a = <0,2*Pi>
```

Tangent is unit circle coordinate with center `(0,0,0)` but shifted by `90` degrees:

```
tx = cos(a (+/-) pi/4)
ty = sin(a (+/-) pi/4)
tz = 0
```

Similarly bi-tangent is:

```
bx = (+/-) cos(a)
by = (+/-) sin(a)
bz = 0
```

and finally normal is

```
nx = 0
ny = 0
nz = (+/-) 1
```

The signs depends on your coordinate system conventions and movement direction.

Comment: Hello,
i tried your code but it doesn't work , seams like the tangents change its angle with the normal when the number of points in the circle is changed

Comment: @BadrDouah then you got bug either in transformations (vectors have to be transformed without offset) or wrong angle conversion/computation (`dangle = 2.0*Pi / (vertexes-1)`) or any other bug... equations are correct. Hope rendering is OK (t,b,n vectors should be multiplied by size and than added to its vertex and render line/arrow from the vertex to the resulting vector/point)